# Reinstallation and UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I'm sorry if my question sound as illiterate.
I have a dual-boot laptop.
Windows on one SSD, Ubuntu on another.
Unfortunately I allocated only 32Gb for Ubuntu and I see it's not enough.
The Ubuntu disk is partitioned in that order:
32Gb - system, 513Mb -EFI, the rest is for data and could be reused.
Is there any way to reinstall Ubuntu using some part of the third (currently data) partition but saving the EFI and not damaging grub and the booting process?

Comment: "only 32Gb for Ubuntu and I see it's not enough" is more than enough for the system itself. If you set it up that your =personal= files are on a shared partition (can be ntfs) you should not go over 20Gb.... albeit you  might want to ditch all snaps as those eat a lot of disk "but saving the EFI and not damaging grub and the booting process?" that is standard. UEFI is only created once per system and new OSes are added to it.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind. I installed Ubuntu from the downloaded ISO. During installation I did not see any option of manual disk space allocations.
Did I miss something?

Comment: You either pick "replace current Ubuntu" or  "something else" and do it manually

Comment: Thanks again, Rinzwind